# How to copy HashMap (not shallow copy) in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, copy

I need to make a copy of `HashMap<Integer, List<MySpecialClass> >` but when I change something in the copy I want the original to stay the same. i.e when I remove something from the `List<MySpecialClass>` from the copy it stays in the `List<MySpecialClass>` in the original.

If I understand it correctly, these two methods create just shallow copy which is not what I want:

```
mapCopy = new HashMap<>(originalMap);
mapCopy = (HashMap) originalMap.clone();
```

Am I right?

Is there a better way to do it than just iterate through all the keys and all the list items and copy it manually?

Comment: Using cloning library saved the day for me!  https://github.com/kostaskougios/cloning

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You're right that a shallow copy won't meet your requirements.  It will have copies of the `List`s from your original map, but those `List`s will refer to the same `List` objects, so that a modification to a `List` from one `HashMap` will appear in the corresponding `List` from the other `HashMap`.

There is no deep copying supplied for a `HashMap` in Java, so you will still have to loop through all of the entries and `put` them in the new `HashMap`.  But you should also make a copy of the `List` each time also.  Something like this:

```
public static HashMap<Integer, List<MySpecialClass>> copy(
    HashMap<Integer, List<MySpecialClass>> original)
{
    HashMap<Integer, List<MySpecialClass>> copy = new HashMap<Integer, List<MySpecialClass>>();
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<MySpecialClass>> entry : original.entrySet())
    {
        copy.put(entry.getKey(),
           // Or whatever List implementation you'd like here.
           new ArrayList<MySpecialClass>(entry.getValue()));
    }
    return copy;
}
```

If you want to modify your individual `MySpecialClass` objects, and have the changes not be reflected in the `List`s of your copied `HashMap`, then you will need to make new copies of them too.

Comment: In the for loop declaration, shoudn't there be original.entrySet() instead of copy.entrySet() ?

Comment: @user3394494 Yes, you're right.  I guess that's what happens when I type the code quickly.  Modified.

Comment: Be aware that this solution will not work as expected, if multiple `keys` in your `Map` reference the same `value` object! Using above method the clone will have new objects for each `value`. Actually, I came here looking for a better option than using a second `Map` from original `values` to cloned `values` during the clone process in such cases.

Answer (score 51):

This does need iteration unfortunately. But it's pretty trivial with Java 8 streams:

```
mapCopy = map.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> List.copyOf(e.getValue())))
```

Comment: I'm not that familiar with streams. When I tried your solution it gives an error :  non-static method getKey() cannot be referenced from a static context, same with getValue(), how to edit it so it works? Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not at a compiler at the moment so I haven't had a chance to test it. Try this and if it doesn't work I'll remove the answer until I've had a chance to test it.

Comment: In a general context, your solution works. The non-static method error seems to be related to the static context of the method of the OP´s problem.

Comment: Wouldn't `getValue()` just be passing a reference though?

Comment: `List.copyOf()` returns a unmodifiable List. In case of copies should `new ArrayList()` be preferred.

Comment: Code snippet has syntax errors, `ArrayList` is a raw type, etc.

Answer (score 26):

Serialize to json and deserialize afterwards:

```
Map<String, Object> originalMap = new HashMap<>();
String json = new Gson().toJson(originalMap);
Map<String, Object> mapCopy = new Gson().fromJson(
    json, new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>() {}.getType());
```

For special classes you might need to [write a custom deserializer](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Writing-a-Deserializer).

Comment: I guess that the downvotes were about the performance penalty of this technique, but IMO this is a legit answer, despite its performance costs.

Comment: Perfect for my test code (where I don't care about performance), of course you can use any json serializer such as `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` : `Map<String, Object> mapCopy = mapper.readValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(originalMap), new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {})`

Comment: This is useful in cases where your data is really deeply referenced.

Comment: This is a real deep copy, guarantees that none of your embedded objects will point to the same reference

Comment: Didn't put a downvote but imho this is pretty bad solution as you have to use external dependency and also you're doing conversion which is not needed (if we say performance is not needed).

Comment: This solution has a problem because Gson will serializes keys using the toString method. For example, toJson for Map<String, Map<Long,Object>> will create a JSON string that has string keys, not numeric. And then the serialization will lead to having Map<String, Map<String,Object>>.

Answer (score 10):

Just use Apache Commons Lang - SerializationUtils.clone();

Something like these:

```
    Map<String, List<MySpecialClass>> originalMap = new HashMap();
    HashMap<String, List<MySpecialClass>> deepCopy = SerializationUtils.clone(new HashMap<>(originalMap));
```

Also make sure MySpecialClass implements Serializable interface.

```
public class MySpecialClass implements Serializable{}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about Java 8, but if you are using Java version 11 or above, then the below code will give you a deep copy of Map.
**If data inside it is of primitively type**

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
HashMap<String, Integer> deepCopiedMap = new HashMap<>(map);
```

Comment: are you sure this won't give you a shallow copy?

Comment: Yes I have tested it multiple times. It returns deep copy of HashMap.

Comment: Indeed it will work for Integer (and probably for other primitive wrappers), but it won't work for other classes. Here's an example of what I mean: https://gist.github.com/horiaconstantin-cpi/e65db961a360fa637cbcd7dc2ab761a1 So, it's a shallow copy.
On the other hand, SerializationUtils.clone will not change the values of the original map.

Answer (score 1):

You are making a copy of the HashMap itself, so changing the HashMap copy will not change the original HashMap (i.e. adding or removing entries), but because the objects you have stored are not primitive types, the List that you retrieve with a given key will be the same whether retrieved from the first or the second Map.

Thus, there is still only ONE copy of that list, referenced by both maps: changing the List changes it no matter which reference you use to access it.

If you want the actual List to be a separate copy, you will have to do as you said: iterate over the entry set of the HashMap and create a copy of each List manually, adding it to the new map as you go.

If there is a better way than that, I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28288729/732328) was good in case you were asking for an immutable copy, but the question indicates you are going to change the list values.

So in this case you need to create a new list for each of the map values as follows:

```
mapCopy = map.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> new ArrayList<>(e.getValue())));
```