# Does .putAll() affect the variable copied?

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I'm totally at loss. Here is my code

HashMap>> themap = new HashMap>>();
HashMap> outerMap = new HashMap>();

```
...
//themap is populated through OnCreate(), and works fine.

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                String currentfragment = "my_string"
                ...
                HashMap<String, HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>>> copymap = copy(themap);
                System.out.println("1" + themap);
                outerMap.putAll(copymap.get(currentfragment));
                System.out.println("2" + themap);
                ...
        }
```

In another method, some values of `themap` are changed. The problem is that when onNavigationItemSelected is called, the first `.println()` prints the right map, with the values changed, and the second `.println()` prints `themap` with its starting values, before they were changed. What did I do wrong?

**EDIT:** I've followed the instructions of [How to copy HashMap (not shallow copy) in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28288546/10266934) , but it still doesn't work. I've updated my previous code, and here is my `copy` method:

```
public static HashMap<String, HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>>> copy(HashMap<String, HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>>> original) {
    HashMap<String, HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>>> copy = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>>> entry : original.entrySet()) {
        HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> copyInnerMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> innerEntry : entry.getValue().entrySet()) {
            HashMap<String, Integer> innerInnerMap = innerEntry.getValue();
            HashMap<String, Integer> copiedInnerInnerMap = new HashMap<>();
            for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> innerInnerMapEntry : innerInnerMap.entrySet()) {
                copiedInnerInnerMap.put(innerInnerMapEntry.getKey(), innerInnerMapEntry.getValue());
            }
            copyInnerMap.put(innerEntry.getKey(), copiedInnerInnerMap);
        }
        copy.put(entry.getKey(), copyInnerMap);
    }
    return copy;
}
```

**EDIT2:** I've updated my copy method so that it's deep enough. 
 Here is the first output: 
1{compu={Day1={Work hours=0, Study hours=0, Day grades=-1, Sheets filled=0, Fun=0}, Day2={Work hours=0, Study hours=0, Day grades=-1, Sheets filled=0, Fun=0}, Day3={Work hours=0, Study hours=0, Day grades=-1, Sheets filled=0, Fun=0}}, chem={Day1={Work hours=0, Study hours=0, Day grades=-1, Sheets filled=0, Fun=0}, Day2={Work hours=0, Study hours=0, Day grades=-1, Sheets filled=0, Fun=0}, Day3={Work hours=0, Study hours=0, Day grades=-1, Sheets filled=0, Fun=0}}, math={Day1={Work hours=0, Study hours=0, Day grades=-1, Sheets filled=0, Fun=0}, **Day2={Work hours=0, Study hours=0, Day grades=-1, Sheets filled=0, Fun=2}**, Day3={Work hours=0, Study hours=0, Day grades=-1, Sheets filled=0, Fun=0}}, physic={Day1={Work hours=0, Study hours=0, Day grades=-1, Sheets filled=0, Fun=0}, Day2={Work hours=0, Study hours=0, Day grades=-1, Sheets filled=0, Fun=0}, Day3={Work hours=0, Study hours=0, Day grades=-1, Sheets filled=0, Fun=0}}, None={Day1={Work hours=0, Study hours=0, Day grades=-1, Sheets filled=0, Fun=0}, Day2={Work hours=0, Study hours=0, Day grades=-1, Sheets filled=0, Fun=2}, Day3={Work hours=0, Study hours=0, Day grades=-1, Sheets filled=0, Fun=0}}}

And the second: 
2{compu={Day1={Work hours=0, Study hours=0, Day grades=-1, Sheets filled=0, Fun=0}, Day2={Work hours=0, Study hours=0, Day grades=-1, Sheets filled=0, Fun=0}, Day3={Work hours=0, Study hours=0, Day grades=-1, Sheets filled=0, Fun=0}}, chem={Day1={Work hours=0, Study hours=0, Day grades=-1, Sheets filled=0, Fun=0}, Day2={Work hours=0, Study hours=0, Day grades=-1, Sheets filled=0, Fun=0}, Day3={Work hours=0, Study hours=0, Day grades=-1, Sheets filled=0, Fun=0}}, math={Day1={Work hours=0, Study hours=0, Day grades=-1, Sheets filled=0, Fun=0}, **Day2={Work hours=0, Study hours=0, Day grades=-1, Sheets filled=0, Fun=0}**, Day3={Work hours=0, Study hours=0, Day grades=-1, Sheets filled=0, Fun=0}}, physic={Day1={Work hours=0, Study hours=0, Day grades=-1, Sheets filled=0, Fun=0}, Day2={Work hours=0, Study hours=0, Day grades=-1, Sheets filled=0, Fun=0}, Day3={Work hours=0, Study hours=0, Day grades=-1, Sheets filled=0, Fun=0}}, None={Day1={Work hours=0, Study hours=0, Day grades=-1, Sheets filled=0, Fun=0}, Day2={Work hours=0, Study hours=0, Day grades=-1, Sheets filled=0, Fun=0}, Day3={Work hours=0, Study hours=0, Day grades=-1, Sheets filled=0, Fun=0}}}

Comment: `putAll` & `put` does not deep copy the object to the new `outerMap`, it just store the reference in the `Map`.

Comment: But why has  `themap` changed after the line where I copy its content? What should I do to copy its content without modifying it?

Comment: maybe outer method changed the value via `outerMap`

Comment: Could you look at my edit, please?

Comment: You should not edit your question to put in the answer. Answers are separate from questions.

Comment: @PatrickParker Sorry, should I re-edit it to put my previous copy method? By the way, I followed your instructions about the way to create deep clones of hashmap using serialization, and I think my problem is about my construction of `themap`. I'm working on it, I will update the thing when I find an answer. Thanks for your help anyways!

Comment: Look, the problem is that you are printing `themap` instead of `copymap`

Answer (score 0):

Since you have 2 level of hashmaps, you are not copying them deep enough.  Try replacing your `outerMap.putAll(copymap.get(currentfragment));` with the following code

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> sample = themap.get(currentfragment);
for (String s : sample.keySet()) {
    outerMap.put(s, new HashMap<>(sample.get(s)));
}
```

Comment: I've tried your code before I updated my copy method with Sun's one, but it didn't work.