# How to copy a Map<object, Object> in java?

Tags: java, hashmap, copy

I use the code in this link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28288546/how-to-copy-hashmap-not-shallow-copy-in-java/28288729)

This is the code that i used on my project

```
 public static Map<Coordinate, Field> copy(Map<Coordinate, Field> original) {
    Map<Coordinate, Field> copy = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<Coordinate, Field> entry : original.entrySet()) {
        copy.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    return copy;
}
```

but it did not work so I used the other one

```
Map<Coordinate, Field> temp = board.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue()));
```

but it still did not work,  so I want to ask if there is other way to copy a Map<Obeject, Object>? or did I do something wrong?

Comment: What does "Does not work" mean?

Comment: Provide the sources in a cut-down example that we can run easily. Reduce the problem to its core https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions (all the downvotes you get are because your question is too broad, has no SSCCE, does not show you tried, and thus we cannot provide a good solution. Update your question).

Comment: I want to make a deep copy of the map, but even when i use the code from this link it was still shallow copy. When i change an element of one map this element will also be changed in the other map

Comment: Sorry i'm not very familiar with stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a copy of the Field object (and, possibly, a copy of the Coordinate object too), instead of putting into a new map the same keys and values.

How to create a copy of your objects depends on the design of your classes. Make a copy constructor, for example.

```
public static Map<Coordinate, Field> copy(Map<Coordinate, Field> original) {
    Map<Coordinate, Field> copy = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<Coordinate, Field> entry : original.entrySet()) {
        Field newField = new Field(entry.getValue()); // make copy here
        copy.put(entry.getKey(), newField);
    }
    return copy;
}
```

Using StreamAPI

```
Map<Coordinate, Field> copy = original.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> new Field(e.getValue)));
```

Comment: Good answer. Short and precise.