# Deep Copy of HashMap in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, deep-copy

I am having difficulty making a deep copy of a HashMap.
I tried the code below from [How to copy HashMap (not shallow copy) in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28288546/how-to-copy-hashmap-not-shallow-copy-in-java/28288729), but List at List.copyOf is giving me an error (Cannot resolve symbol 'List') and I'm not sure what to replace it with. If there is any other way to make a deep copy of HashMap, I would love to hear.

```
private HashMap<Character, ArrayList<int[]>> board;

public Vertex(HashMap<Character, ArrayList<int[]>> inputboard) {
        board = new HashMap<>();
        this.board = copy(inputboard);
}

public HashMap<Character, ArrayList<int[]>> copy (HashMap<Character, ArrayList<int[]>> original) {  
        HashMap<Character, ArrayList<int[]>> copy = original.entrySet().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> List.copyOf(e.getValue())));
        return copy;
}
```

Before I used the above code, I also tried this from [How to copy HashMap (not shallow copy) in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28288546/how-to-copy-hashmap-not-shallow-copy-in-java/28288729) but it did not make a deep copy

```
private HashMap<Character, ArrayList<int[]>> board;

public Vertex(HashMap<Character, ArrayList<int[]>> inputboard) {
        board = new HashMap<>();
        this.board = copy(inputboard);
}

public HashMap<Character, ArrayList<int[]>> copy (HashMap<Character, ArrayList<int[]>> original) {
       HashMap<Character, ArrayList<int[]>> copy = new HashMap<>();
       for (Map.Entry<Character, ArrayList<int[]>> entry : original.entrySet()) {
            copy.put(entry.getKey(), new ArrayList<>(entry.getValue()));
       }
       return copy;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to copy the `int[]`s too?

Comment: Are you using something older than Java 10? Otherwise `List.copyOf` should be available, and you just need to `import java.util.List;`.

Comment: Yes, I want to copy `int []` s too. Not just keys. When I do `import java.util.List;`, I get an error that says Map <Object, Object> is provided while HashMap<Character,ArrayList<int[]>> is really required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both ways you showed doesn't copy the `int[]`, i.e. not copying as deep as you want.

The first way actually returns a `Map<Character, List<int[]>>` rather than the `HashMap<Character, ArrayList<int[]>>` you want. I would recommend that you [program to interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface) and change your method to return a `Map<Character, List<int[]>>` instead, then you can use streams like this:

```
public Map<Character, List<int[]>> copy (HashMap<Character, ArrayList<int[]>> original) {
    Map<Character, List<int[]>> copy = original.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Entry::getKey,
            e -> e.getValue().stream().map(x -> Arrays.copyOf(x, x.length)).collect(Collectors.toList())
        ));
    return copy;
}
```

If you really don't want to change the return type, you'd have to pass more arguments to specify the concrete types you want:

```
public HashMap<Character, ArrayList<int[]>> copy (HashMap<Character, ArrayList<int[]>> original) {
    HashMap<Character, ArrayList<int[]>> copy = original.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Entry::getKey,
            e -> e.getValue().stream().map(x -> Arrays.copyOf(x, x.length)).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)),
            (x, y) -> x,
            HashMap::new
        ));
    return copy;
}
```

Otherwise, you can use the traditional for loops:

```
public HashMap<Character, ArrayList<int[]>> copy (HashMap<Character, ArrayList<int[]>> original) {
    HashMap<Character, ArrayList<int[]>> copy = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<Character, ArrayList<int[]>> entry : original.entrySet()) {
        ArrayList<int[]> listCopy = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int[] array: entry.getValue()) {
            listCopy.add(Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length));
        }
        copy.put(entry.getKey(), listCopy);
    }
    return copy;
}
```

Notice that in all three code snippets, I have used `Arrays.copyOf` to copy the `int[]`.