# How to do a deep copy of a Map of Maps using streams?

Tags: java, java-stream

The easiest way is to loop through, but that would be verbose and I would prefer a cleaner solution with Java 8.

[This post over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28288546/how-to-copy-hashmap-not-shallow-copy-in-java) recommends

```
mapCopy = map.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> List.copyOf(e.getValue())))
```

For copying `HashMap<Integer, List>`, but what I have is `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>`. I tried the above method for lists as well but for some reason, `e.getKey()` and `e.getValue()` both "cannot be resolved" even though IntelliJ auto-predicts it as a valid method, and `e` refers to a `Map.Entry`

I'm not super adept at using streams, so I can't figure out why the above doesn't work, or how to accomplish what I want.

Comment: Can the value contain other Maps? What type of Map is the value?

Comment: Edited! HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>>

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `HashMap` constructor to create a (shallow) copy of each value in the original `Map`.

```
Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> result = map.entrySet().stream()
   .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> new HashMap<>(e.getValue())));
```